# Hyper-V is not found on windows 7 bios

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, bios

I'm currently using Windows 7 Home OS with 2GB RAM and cores and I was trying to install x64 Ubuntu on most recent version Oracle VirtualBox for college assignment. All I got is the following occured errors:

> The native API dll was not found (C:\Windows\system32\WinHvPlatform.dll) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
> AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS) (VERR_SVM_DISABLED).

Hyper-V is not available on on/off windows feature. I have tried every tutorials on the internet and none of them works. I was searching for the copy of Hyper-v but it couldn't be found. There was details it could restored from RSAT and some management tool. Tried RSAT but it had undefined behavior and done nothing other than trying to do windows update. There was also comments on some pages saying that since windows 7 is no longer supported by Microsoft so there's no way to get the architecture. When I checked bios menu I couldn't see any options regarding virtualization config and it has very little options.

Can this be resolved?

Comment: You don't need or want Hyper-V and neither does the error message name it. You need to enable hardware-assisted virtualization in your BIOS/UEFI setup. Provide the exact make and model of your mainboard and we can guide you.

Comment: @Daniel B InsydeH20 Setup Utility.
 System BIOS version : v.2.0.9.
 There's only Information, Main, Security, Boot and Exit menu

Comment: Windows 7 is long out of support and you need something stronger than Home to get into Virtual Machines.    [I checked bios menu I couldn't see any options regarding virtualization]  ....  It appears not to have hardware virtualization. Perhaps time to replace the computer.

Comment: Aspire E1-422, seems like there's similar issue to it. Is a BIOS feature really related to the hardware, since it runs as an application?

Comment: Hardware Virtualization is a hardware feature, not a software application.

Comment: Hyper-V wasn’t a feature on most editions of Windows 7. If the option to enable hardware virtualization isn’t present i the firmware then your hardware doesn’t support it.

Answer (score 2):

From the information I found (mostly others trying the same) it would appear that Acer decided not to expose the hardware-assisted virtualization switch on your device. That means you cannot turn it on, which in turn means you cannot run virtual machines with 64-bit guests. However, you can still run virtual machines with 32-bit guests.

Someone with a different Acer laptop apparently managed to enable hardware-assisted virtualization by messing directly with EFI variables. Because I cannot verify this *and* incorrect values in EFI variables can *permanently* brick your PC/laptop, I strongly recommend you do not do this.

With just 2 GiB of RAM, running 64-bit guests is pointless anyway. If you absolutely must use a 64-bit OS for something, you will either have to multi-boot or simply use a different machine.

Using virtual machines on cloud service platforms (Amazon Web Services, Google Cloud Platform, Microsoft Azure, DigitalOcean, …) is super cheap as long as you only use them for a short time (a few hours). If you need the VM for longer, the big three are probably not for you. DigitalOcean (and others) may still be cheap enough.

Comment: `With just 2 GiB of RAM, running 64-bit guests is pointless anyway.` .. thank you for saying this.  It was the first red flag I spotted.